# How to drop duplicates in Pandas DataFrame by checking for a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataFrame:

```
ID | a |
-------- 
 1 | 10  
 1 | 40 
 2 | 5
 2 | 10 


df.drop_duplicates('ID')
```

I want to drop duplicate rows by checking for duplicate entries in the column 'ID', and retain the row which has a value of 10 in column a.

I want my resulting df to look like

```
ID | a 
-------- 
 1 | 10
 2 | 10
```

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where a duplicated IDs does not have a `10` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extended your data to include a datapoint with no duplicates, and triplicate where the value of 10 is duplicated.

> I want to drop duplicate rows by checking for duplicate entries in the column 'ID', and retain the row which has a value of 10 in column a.

I am interpreting this as retaining rows with no duplicates and retaining duplicates only if the value in column `a` equals 10 (which would lead to duplicate values of the same ID where each had a value of 10).

I use `Counter` to compute the number of occurrences of each `ID`.  I then create a list of duplicates and a DataFrame mask for these duplicated `ID` rows.

Finally, I use `.loc` to select rows which are not in my mask (i.e. those that are not duplicated) or rows that are duplicated but have the value 10 in column `a`.  At this point, it is still possible to have duplicates with the value 10 for column `a`.  If this is not desired, you can add a `.drop_duplicates()` to the result.

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], 'a': [10, 40, 5, 10, 10, 5]})
>>> df
   ID   a
0   1  10
1   1  40
2   2   5
3   2  10
4   2  10
5   3   5

c = Counter(df.ID)
dups = [n for n in c if c[n] > 1]
mask = df.ID.isin(dups)
result = df.loc[(~mask) | ((mask) & (df.a == 10)), :]
>>> result
   ID   a
0   1  10
3   2  10
4   2  10
5   3   5

>>> result.drop_duplicates()
   ID   a
0   1  10
3   2  10
5   3   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the values in `a` before drop duplicates with:

```
df = df[df['a']==10]
```

Comment: I only gave the condition as an example. My real conditions are more complicated.